# Get windows explorer font size of current user using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is this possible with C# or do I need to do P/Invoke? I was thinking it's an easy way to determine which font size to set for my ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under class SystemFonts.  I don't think you need more than the default namespaces for this.

for example:

```
string name = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont.FontFamily.Name;
float size = SystemFonts.IconTitleFont.Size;
```